# To determine if the given quadratic forms are equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

> Let $p$ and $q$ be quadratic forms given by $$q(x,y,z,w)=x^2+y^2+z^2+bw^2$$ $$p(x,y,z,w)=x^2+y^2+czw$$ Then which of the following statements are true?
>
> 1) $p$ and $q$ are equivalent over $\mathbb{C}$, if $b$ and $c$ are non-zero complex numbers.
>
> 2) $p$ and $q$ are equivalent over $\mathbb{R}$, if $b$ and $c$ are nonzero real numbers.
>
> 3) $p$ and $q$ are equivalent non zero real numbers with $b$ negative.
>
> 4) $p$ and $q$ are not equivalent over $\mathbb{R}$, if $c$=0.

The corresponding matrices are
 $
   Q=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & b \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

$
   P=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{c}{2} \\
   0 & 0 & \frac{c}{2} & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

which are equivalent if and only if rank(P)=rank(Q) which is true when $b$ and $c$ are non-zero numbers. Therefore all the four options are correct. But the answer key says that option 2) is false. Can anyone help me find the mistake?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia#Law_of_inertia_for_quadratic_forms)

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*- Let $p$ and $n$ respectively denote the number of positive and negative eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix $A$. Then $rank(A)=p+n$ and $signature (A)=p-n$.

For $\mathbb R$-equivalent, you need their rank equality and signature equality.